# MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, movieclip, moviepy, oserror

I am making a proyect that i need to take one video and extract its audio. after extracting the audio, we use this audio to transcribe and put it in a txt file. Below i put the code i have been using. This evening i get an error i have never had.
`

```
from numpy import clip
import speech_recognition as sr
import moviepy.editor as mp
from moviepy.editor import *



#lectura de video
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("/Users/leti/OneDrive - Universidad Europea de Madrid/Proyecto Computacion I/Videos sin procesar/Sergio Procesados/Arroz_meloso_carabineros.mp4").subclip(0,150)

#extraemos el audio
clip.audio.write_audiofile("/Users/leti/OneDrive - Universidad Europea de Madrid/Proyecto Computacion I/Videos sin procesar/Sergio Procesados/Arroz_meloso_carabineros.wav")

#iniciamos el speechrecognition
r = sr.Recognizer()

#leemos el archivo audio extraido
audio = sr.AudioFile("/Users/leti/OneDrive - Universidad Europea de Madrid/Proyecto Computacion I/Videos sin procesar/Sergio Procesados/Arroz_meloso_carabineros.wav")
print("audio extraido")

#lectura de audio
with audio as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    clean_file = r.record(source)

print("lectura terminada")
#reconocemos la voz del audio
result = r.recognize_google(clean_file,language="es-ES")



print("")
print(result)
#escribimos el texto en un nuevo archivo txt
with open('/Users/leti/OneDrive - Universidad Europea de Madrid/Proyecto Computacion I/Videos sin procesar/Sergio Procesados/Trans/Arroz_meloso_carabineros.txt','w') as file:
    file.write("RECOGNIZED SPEECH: \n") 
    file.write(result)
    #file.write(" "+result)

print("\nEscritura terminada")
```

``

the error I have had is as follows:
`

```
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file /Users/leti/OneDrive - Universidad Europea de Madrid/Proyecto Computacion I/Videos sin procesar/Sergio Procesados/Arroz_meloso_carabineros.mp4.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
/Users/leti/OneDrive - Universidad Europea de Madrid/Proyecto Computacion I/Videos sin procesar/Sergio Procesados/Arroz_meloso_carabineros.mp4: Invalid argument
```

`

Comment: From the last line `../Arroz_meloso_carabineros.mp4: Invalid argument` it seems the path to the .mp4 file is the problem! Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: the path is correct, i have changed the path several time and the mistake keeps appearing.

Comment: did you try opening the file with a program or doing another operation with ffmpeg (copy, cut, whatever) or doing the same operation for another video to understand whether the problem lies in the .mp4 file itself or with the ffmpeg command?